# How to find the inode of all files in Linux with Python?

Tags: python, linux, file, directory, inode

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
import os, sys

# Open a file
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT )

# Now get  the touple
info = os.fstat(fd)

print "File Info :", info

# Now get uid of the file
print "UID of the file :%d" % info.st_uid

# Now get gid of the file
print "GID of the file :%d" % info.st_gid

# Close opened file
os.close( fd)
```

Comment: "All files" means what? You want to trawl the entire filesystem? A specific directory? Something else? (And do you have a particularly good reason to want to use Python? A subprocess invoking `find / -printf '%i\t%P\0'` might well be faster to run, and the output will be trivial to unambiguously parse).

Comment: What specific part of what you want differs from what you have? Do you know how to retrieve stat data, but not where the inode is in that? Do you know how to retrieve stat data for a single file, but not how to recurse? If you have *both* those questions, they should probably be asked separately (or, even better, searched for separately, as each almost certainly exists in the knowledgebase individually)

Comment: yes i want get list of all files system with inode , name ,size and ...

Comment: very poor question, with a piece of code not matching the question and no further text..

Answer (score 7):

The [*os.stat*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) function returns directory information about a file.  The [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) is stored in *st_ino* field.   Here's some code to get you started:

```
>>> import glob
>>> import os
>>> for filename in glob.glob('*.py'):
        print(os.stat(filename).st_ino, filename)
```

To get the filesize, use the *st_size* field:

```
>>> os.stat(filename).st_size       
1481
```

To get the filename, just print the *filename* variable:

```
>>> print(filename)
'hello.py'
```

Comment: I'd read "all" to mean, well, *all* -- ie. that they're looking for a solution that recurses into subdirectories a la `os.walk()`.

Comment: Can I return the file name and file size with this code?